Suddenly getting composer errors when updating extension?
Magento 2.4.6-p5
Suddenly I am getting weird error messages when updating one of my extensions.
It starts with

Install of ramsey/collection failed ...

and goes on and on. I am using composer 2.2 and from what I can see it started out of nowhere. I tried removing the vendor folder and running composer install, same errors pop up.
ANY ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks
